# Using pipes-parse to preserve leftovers with a map

Tags: haskell, conduit, haskell-pipes

I'm trying to understand how pipes-parse 3.0 works for cases besides `span` and `splitAt`, and can't quite figure out how to get things working. The basic idea is that I have an isomorphism, and I'd like to map all input values to convert from type `A` to type `B`. Then, I'd like all leftovers to be converted back from `B` to `A`. How would I accomplish this in `pipes-parse`?

For comparison, the code would look like the following in `conduit`:

```
import           Control.Applicative ((<$>), (<*>))
import           Data.Conduit        (yield, ($$), (=$=))
import           Data.Conduit.Extra  (fuseLeftovers)
import qualified Data.Conduit.List   as CL

newtype A = A Int
    deriving Show
newtype B = B Int
    deriving Show

atob (A i) = (B i)
btoa (B i) = (A i)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    let src = mapM_ (yield . A) [1..10]
    res <- src $$ (,,,)
        <$> fuseLeftovers (map btoa) (CL.map atob) CL.peek
        <*> CL.take 3
        <*> (CL.map atob =$= CL.take 3)
        <*> CL.consume
    print res
```

**EDIT**: To clarify, here's the output of my above code:

```
(Just (B 1),[A 1,A 2,A 3],[B 4,B 5,B 6],[A 7,A 8,A 9,A 10])
```

Note that the original stream is of type `A`. We're converting to `B` and peeking at the first element, then taking the next 3 elements as type `A`, then taking the following three as `B`, and finally taking the remainder as `A`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did it by introducing an auxiliary lens combinator, `piso :: Iso' a b -> Iso' (Producer a m r) (Producer b m r)`

```
import           Control.Applicative
import           Control.Lens               (view, from, zoom, iso, Iso')
import           Control.Monad.State.Strict (evalState)
import           Pipes
import           Pipes.Core                 as Pc
import qualified Pipes.Parse                as Pp
import qualified Pipes.Prelude              as P

newtype A = A Int
    deriving Show
newtype B = B Int
    deriving Show

atob (A i) = B i
btoa (B i) = A i

ab :: Iso' A B
ab = iso atob btoa

piso :: Monad m => Iso' a b -> Iso' (Producer a m r) (Producer b m r)
piso i = iso (P.map (view i) <-<) (>-> P.map (view $ from i))

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let src = P.map atob <-< P.map A <-< each [1..10]
  let parser = (,,) <$> zoom (Pp.splitAt 1) Pp.peek
                    <*> zoom (Pp.splitAt 3 . piso (from ab)) Pp.drawAll
                    <*> Pp.drawAll
  let res = evalState parser src
  print res
```

Here `src` is a `Producer B m r` and `parser` a `Parser B m (Maybe B, [A], [B])`. I think the heart of this is that leftovers are just what happens in the `Parser`-State bound `Producer` after some prior parsing actions. You can thus use `zoom` just like normal to modify that `Producer` however you like.

Note that we could flip the order of the lenses and do `zoom (piso (from ab) . Pp.splitAt 3) Pp.drawAll` but since lenses descend from left to right that means that we're modifying the entire `Producer` prior to focusing on the next three elements. Using the order in my primary example reduces the number of mappings between `A` and `B`.

```
view (Pp.splitAt 3 . piso (from ab))
  :: Monad m => Producer B m x -> (Producer A m (Producer B m x))
  -- note that only the outer, first Producer has been mapped over, the protected,
  -- inner producer in the return type is isolated from `piso`'s effect

view (piso (from ab) . Pp.splitAt 3)
  :: Monad m => Producer B m x -> (Producer A m (Producer A m x))
```

Comment: I updated my question to clarify. The example I gave performed slightly different work. It seems like it should be trivial to convert what you've provided into the original functionality, but I haven't been able to.

Comment: Scratch that last comment, I think I figured it out: https://gist.github.com/snoyberg/8888998. I added some trace statements to try to understand your comments about reducing the number of mappings. Now it looks like the whole stream is converted back and forth, is that what you were getting at?

Comment: @MichaelSnoyman The conversion back and forth seems to come from the the `zoom (piso ab) Pp.peek` with out that portion only the only the middle three elements have `atob` called them, as I would expect.

Comment: Ah, hah—I read your example code, read your description, then gunned for it without realizing I'd changed the example slightly. Using `zoom (piso i)` will run the entire `Producer` both in and out of the isomorphism.

Comment: @Davorak I added a comment on the gist, but I'll add one here too. The point of this exercise is to test out leftover preserving on a stream transformation. Getting rid of that line, or changing it to something "equivalent," means we're no longer using leftover preserving, or at least no longer testing a proper stream transformation.

Comment: @MichaelSnoyman The solution by J Abrahamson, the solution in your gist and my modification to it only seem to work when the two types you are streaming over are isomorphic. My modified parser does not seem more restrictive.  If the two types are not isomorphic, like your example with utf8-encoded bytes, then it seems like you need a different solution then one provided here.

Comment: I'm talking about a case where it may not be the same number of elements for the two streams. With utf8, four bytes may turn into just one character. So peeking at the byte stream and then converting to a character wouldn't work. You'd need to convert to characters and then peek.

Comment: Note that `pipes-text` has a `decodeUTF8` lens.  The trick is that if decoding fails it returns the remainder as a `Producer ByteString m r` in its return value.  It's not a perfect isomorphism, but it's good enough for most purposes.